# Move variable from one jform to another

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am new to java programming and need help with calling a java method from another jform class. I basically need to connect the second jform named Prizes.java to the MySQL database and call a method(maybe the Fillforms?) so that the same row of data in the MySQL table is edited(controlled by "ID"). I tired to set a return value on Fillforms but it appears it will not work with a try method. So I'm not sure if I need to make a new method or can I change the one I have?
Tickets.java

```
package Tickets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;

public class Tickets extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
int curRow = 0;

    public Tickets() {
        initComponents();
        DoConnect();
    }
    public void DoConnect( ) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://&&.&&.&&.&&&:3306/"; 
        String dbName = "pos";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
        String userName = "Switcher"; 
        String password = "*****"; 
        try { 
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password); 
            //conn.close(); 
            stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM instock";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next(); 
            Fillforms();   
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }

    public void Fillforms(){
    int id_col = 0;
  try{
      id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString( id_col );
            String game_name = rs.getString("Game");
            String mf_id = rs.getString("MF_ID");
            String dist_id = rs.getString("Dist_ID");
            String part_no = rs.getString("Part_No");
            String game_type = rs.getString("Game_Type");
            String inv_num = rs.getString("Invoice_num");
            String date_purch = rs.getString("Date_purch");
            String date_placed = rs.getString("Date_placed");
            String date_removed = rs.getString("Date_removed");
            String inplay = rs.getString("Inplay");
            String ticket_cost = rs.getString("Ticket_cost");
            String num_tickets = rs.getString("Num_tickets");
            String ideal_gross = rs.getString("Ideal_gross");
            String ideal_prizes = rs.getString("Ideal_prizes");
            String ideal_net = rs.getString("Ideal_net");
            String game_cost = rs.getString("Game_cost");
            String unsold_amt = rs.getString("Unsold_amt");
            String actual_gross = rs.getString("Actual_gross");
            String actual_prizes = rs.getString("Actual_prizes");
            String actual_net = rs.getString("Actual_net");
            String bin = rs.getString("Bin");
            String last_sale = rs.getString("Last_Sale");
            String unsold_tick = rs.getString("Unsold_tickets");
            String serial = rs.getString("Serial");


            textGame.setText(game_name);
            textID.setText(id);
            textSerial.setText(serial);
            textPartNum.setText(part_no);
            textManID.setText(mf_id);
            textDistID.setText(dist_id);
            textGameType.setText(game_type);
            textInvoiceNum.setText(inv_num);
            textInvoiceDate.setText(date_purch);
            textDatePlaced.setText(date_placed);
            textDateRem.setText(date_removed);
            textCostTicket.setText(ticket_cost);
            textNumTickets.setText(num_tickets);
            textIdealGross.setText(ideal_gross);
            textIdealPrizes.setText(ideal_prizes);
            textUnsoldValue.setText(unsold_amt);
            textActualGross.setText(actual_gross);
            textActualPrizes.setText(actual_prizes);
            textActualNet.setText(actual_net);
            textBin.setText(bin);
            textUnsoldTickets.setText(unsold_tick);
            textIdealNet.setText(ideal_net);
            textGameCost.setText(game_cost);

  }  catch (SQLException err) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Tickets.this, err.getMessage());
}

}
```